# Posting an android game to market/Google play

Tags: android, upload, google-play, currency

i am almost finished with my first android game which i would like to earn some money on. I am wondering if i should upload it for a couple of bucks or if i'll upload a free and paid version with adds on the free one. What do you think i'll earn most on??? Please share your thoughts and let me now. Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is you need both.  You need to provide a free trial of some sort, so people can see if they like you product.  This one could contain ads.  In order to make money on ads, you need to get lots and lots of views in your app.

You should also offer an "ad free" version so people who do like your app can support you, and get rid of the ads.

Comment: Thanks both, i'll make a free and paid version with ads on the free one

Answer (score 1):

You will earn almost nothing (I rule out that you already are successful and experienced game designer able to provide something unique).   If you upload paid version, you will get no downloads.  If you put free version and promote properly - you will get some downloads. And if game hits you will get some more downloads etc.  So your best income source would be advertising - but do not expect much out of it.

Comment: Thanks both, i'll make a free and paid version with ads on the free one

Answer (score 0):

I am about to jump into the "publishing games in android" thing, and I am kind of in the same phase you were when you wrote this post(am almost finished coding the game, thinking of publishing)

Now that its one and a half years since you had posted this game(I assume you did),
I would love to know how did everything go- could you share your experience?

Comment: HI! It's a tough market, did'nt make much Money on This one, but I'm working on something big now - which will hopefully sell. Create a trial app, and a paid ad free version - and also spread the word. Let people know of your app - that's the biggest problem, to stand out of the crowd